# Javascript object.hasOwnProperty() vs Reflect.has()

Tags: javascript

I experienced using `object.hasOwnProperty('property')` to validate Javascript object and recently noticed that `Reflect.has()` also used to validate the object properties.
However, both are almost the same functionality but I would like to understand the best practice to use `Reflect.has()` and which one will cause better performance.

I noticed that if it is not an object then `hasOwnProperty` is not throwing any error but `Reflect.has()` throws an error.

```js
var object1 = {
  property1: 42
};
//expected output: true
console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('property1'));

console.log(Reflect.has(object1, 'property1'));
// expected output: true
console.log(Reflect.has(object1, 'property2'));
// expected output: false
console.log(Reflect.has(object1, 'toString'));

//For Negative case scenario
var object2 ="";
// expected output: false
console.log(object2.hasOwnProperty('property1'))
// error
console.log(Reflect.has(object2, 'property1'));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One major difference is that `Reflect.has` will check whether any of the object's *internal prototypes* have the key, whereas `hasOwnProperty` only checks whether the object itself has the key:

```js
const proto = { foo: 'foo' };
const obj = Object.create(proto);
console.log(Reflect.has(obj, 'foo'));
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('foo'));
```

If you want to check whether the object itself has the property, and isn't an inherited property, you should definitely use `hasOwnProperty`.

Another important difference is that `Reflect.has` requires ES6 support, whereas `hasOwnProperty` has existed since ES3, so if you use `Reflect.has` and require support for older browsers, make sure to include a polyfill.

Comment: Thank you. If I am using Reflect.has(), it will not support by default? How to add polyfill here

Comment: You can use:
https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect
https://github.com/zloirock/core-js

Answer (score 2):

Reflect api is a part of ECMAScript 2015 whether hasOwnProperty is available in current standard. Their behavior may differ too. So if they function identically it only depends on whether you want to support older browsers or not.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

You can polyfill it with seral libraries that can be found on github/npmjs like:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata

https://www.npmjs.com/package/harmony-reflect